# DOJO 1.8. FilteringSelect in DataGrid fed by FileItemReadStore is not working

Tags: json, datagrid, store, dojo

I'm struggeling with DOJO 1.8 and Datagrid. I would like to put a filteringSelect into a Datagrid cell. The widget should be fed by a Store. The store is fed by an AJAX request and works find. Also the select widget shows up, but it is empty. There's neither a value nor an option to see in the browser:

The Code for the Store:

```
     // AJAX REQUEST TO GET PROJECTS AND SAVE AS STORE
 require(['dojo/request', 'dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore'], function(request, ItemFileReadStore){
    request('project/json/getprojects', {
        handleAs: 'json'
    }).then(function(json){
       var projectStore = new ItemFileReadStore({data: {'identifier':'id', 'label':'label', 'items': json}});   
    });
```

The JSON I retrieve looks like this:

```
[{"id":2,"name":"Bilder-App","customer":"Company A","label":"Company A >> Bilder-App"},{"id":8,"name":"Zeiterfassung","customer":"Company B","label":"Company B >> Zeiterfassung"}]
```

The goal is that the select-box shows the "label" field visually and saves "id" to the store/grid.

Here's the code of the grid_layout for the cell:

```
{field: "project_id", name: "Kunde/Projekt", type: dojox.grid.cells._Widget, widgetClass: dijit.form.Select, widgetProps: {store: projectStore,  searchAttr: "label"} },
```

Is anyone able to help me with that?

MANY THANKS!

AFX

---

Here is the working formatter:

```
  // PROJECT-ID FORMATTER
     function formatProjectId(value, index){ 
            var item =  projectStore.get(value);
            var label = item['label'];  
             return label; 
      }
```

However, there's one slight problem: Right when I selected the  item in the select box it shows the id in the field. When I leave the field it gets formatted correctly.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK!

I was able to find a solution.

First of all, I changed to Memory-Store, since I figured out that the ItemFileReadStore wasn't working correctly.

I read somewhere, that you need to require the 'dijit/form/FilteringSelect' specifically. So I did that.

So my field in the layout variable looks like this:

```
 {field: "project_id", name: "Kunde/Projekt", type: dojox.grid.cells._Widget, widgetClass: dijit.form.FilteringSelect, widgetProps: {searchAttr: "id", labelAttr: "label", store: projectStore}},
```

My Store has an array of data consisting of the fields 'id' and 'label'...so it gave the field those attributes! And BOOOOM...it works!

Now I have to add a formatter-function to format the displayed IDs onces they were edited.

Posting about this soon!

Have a good one,
AFX

Comment: Can you provide more details on this?? 
Like the formatter function.. ?